# know if smooth scrolling is enabled in browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, scroll, smoothing

I want to use `window.scrollBy` on my site to scroll page on some events, but I want to do it the way user has set their browser to scroll (smoothly or not) to not disturb users.

But even thought I have smooth scrolling enabled in my firefox when I just use scrollBy function it scrolls not smoothly, ofc I can enable smooth scroll myself as a param but then if I have smooth scroll disabled in my browser setting - it'd scroll smoothly anyway (not the way it's set in the browser), ofc param behavior "auto" isn't actually auto but just "not smooth", what the hell do I do now??

is there a global value for smooth scroll user current setting I could just read and use maybe?

Comment: I have the exact same question - did you manage to solve this in the meantime? 
I fear that this is something that browsers would have to implement first, like setting a default value in the browser css based on the smoothscroll setting.

Comment: @user828591 ideally scroll without specified options should use browser setting for smooth scrolling already and there shouldn't be any need to set it specifically

there is no solution here except reporting it as a bug to mozilla it seems